# Get only nonunique rows from table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, group-by

How can I get only non-unique values from 2 columns table:

I need something like

```
Select a,b from tableA group by a,b having count(a,b)>1
```

Now of cource it doesn't because of count.

I've forgot how can I do it and maybe thank to you I get known new simply solution :)

Best regards

Comment: The count function requires 1 argument(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should work.

```
Select a,b from tableA group by a,b having count(*)>1
```

count cannot have multiple fields in it. either star which indicates everything or a single field which basically does the same thing as star unless that field's value is NULL in which case it is not counted.

Comment: Looks like we answered at the same time! :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT a, b, COUNT(*) FROM   tableA GROUP BY a, b HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I've included the COUNT(*) so you can see how many there are for each case.

Comment: See MSDN Documentation for SQL COUNT here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx